# Is anybody happily using Google Analytics with big websites? (million+ pages, million+ monthly visitors)

Tags: google-analytics

I was a happy customer of Google Analytics starting from the Urchin times. But something strange happened a few months ago and GA started showing a fake URL called "(other)" that is credited between 5% and 45% of all site traffic. I've tried filtering out some URL parameters to reduce the number of pages. Currently GA shows only 150,000 pages on my site, which is well below the half million limit that some people are talking about. Still, the page "(other)" is showing as the most popular page on my site.

Is anybody else struggling with this issue? I am wondering whether this could be a scalability issue. My site has been growing over the years, and currently doing 1.25 million unique monthly visitors and over 10 million pageviews. The site itself has around half a million pages. If you are successfully using GA with a bigger website than mine, please share your story. Are you using the Sampling feature of their tracking script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a huge website like and I would not use a Free Analytics. I would use something like [Web trends](http://www.webtrends.com/) or some other paid analytics. We cannot blame GA for this after all its a free service ;-)

GA has page view limits too. (5 Million page views)

Just curious. How long did you take to add the analytics code to your pages? ;-)

Comment: I was using WebTrends before switching to Google Analytics. WebTrends was Ok but we hit the point where the log files for one day took more than 24 hours to import on a beefy server.
GA code was very easy to inject into my website. Definitely less than an hour. Most pages are based on the same template, so we just added their script to the template.
Good point on the 5 million limit. In my case, the GA account is linked to AdWords, so this limit should not apply.

Answer (score 7):

In *[Advanced Web Metrics with Google Analytics](http://www.advanced-web-metrics.com/blog/2008/04/07/book-launch-advanced-web-metrics-with-google-analytics/)*  Brian Clifton writes that above a certain number of page views, Google Analytics is no more able to list all the seperate page views and starts aggregating the small amount ones under „(other)” entry.

> By default, Google Analytics collects
>   pageview data for every visitor. For
>   very high traffic sites, the amount
>   of data can be overwhelming, leading
>   to large parts of the “long tail” of
>   information to be missing from your
>   reports, simply because they are too
>   far down in the report tables. You can
>   diminish this issue by creating
>   separate profiles of visitor
>   segments—for example, /blog, /forum,
>   /support, etc. However, another option
>   is to [sample your visitors](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setSampleRate).

Answer (score 1):

I get about 3.5 million hits a month on one of my sites using GA. I don't see (other) listed anywhere. Specifically what report are you viewing? Is (other) the title or URL of the page?

Comment: The "Top Content" report is the best example - the fake URL "(other)" is always on top. 
May I ask how many pages do you see in GA when you open the "Top Content" report for your site? I suspect that GA starts showing "(other)" only when the number of distinct URLs gets "too high". In my case, GA reports around 150,000 pages while in reality there are a lot more pages on my site...

Comment: It shows the top 10 of 431,900 for the last month.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a loooonnnngggg way on Google Analytics. I had a site doing about 25mm uniques/mo. and it was working for us just fine. The "other" bucket fills up when you hit a certain limit of pageviews/etc.  The way around this is to create different filters on the data.

Answer (score 1):

For a huge website (millions of page views per day), you should try out SnowPlow:

https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow

This will give you granular data down to the individual page URLs (unlike Google Analytics at that volume) and, because it is based on Hadoop/Hive/Infobright, it will happily scale up to billions of page views.

Answer (score 0):

Its more to do with a daily limit of unique values for a metric they will report on. if your site uses querystring parameters, all those unique values and parameter variations are seen as separate pages and cause the report to go over the limit of 50,000 unique values in a day for a metric.  To eliminate, you should add all the big culprits querystring names to be ignored, making sure however to not add any search querystring names if search is on.

On the Profile Settings, add them to the Exclude URL Query Parameters textbox field, delimited by commas.  Once I did this, the (other) went away from the reports. It takes affect at the point they are added, previous days will still have (other) displaying.